# Is it a bad practice to use the "." symbol in Mongodb collection name?

Tags: mongodb

I have a quite big web application. The application is split in multiple modules. Each modules can create multiple collections in the Mongodb database.

Since each modules can create collections, There is a possibility to have collision between them so I'm currently trying to "namespace" my collections in a elegant way.

Here is an example of what **I would like to do**:

*Module1 creates these collections:*

```
module1.items
module1.employees
```

*Module2 creates these collections:*

```
module2.items // Avoid collision with module1
module2.animals
```

Here is an example of what **I would like to avoid**:

*Module1 creates these collections:*

```
module1items
module1employees
```

*Module2 creates these collections:*

```
module2items // Avoid collision with module1
module2animals
```

Now I wonder if it is a bad pratice to use "." in the collection name. Usually, the "." is used to split the database name from the collections name like `db.mydatabase.mycollection` so I am concerned about possible bugs I might encounter if I use the "." method to namespace my collection name.

[EDIT]

Here is a quote I found on the mongodb website:

*For an example **acme.users** namespace, **acme** is the database name and **users** is the collection name. Period characters can occur in collection names, so that **acme.user.history** is a valid namespace, with **acme** as the database name, and **user.history** as the collection name.*
[Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/)

Adding that to [Stephane Godbillon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16568284/613568) (mentioning gridFS), I now feel quite safe about using that naming convention. Now I just hope that the ODM I use (mongoose) will not cause any problem :).

Comment: `.` actually denote a valid type of sub collection, so no it is not bad practice, though you might need to use `getCollection()` directly more often instead of the magics

Comment: just dont use dots in your fieldnames and your should be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this without any problem. In fact even GridFS works with collections named this way (`fs.files` and `fs.chunks`).